# What is the difference between Pipeline and Project in Jenkins?

Tags: unix, jenkins

What is the difference between Pipeline and Project in Jenkins? Can I call a project from Pipeline. If Yes how using linux node?

Answer (score 9):

In Jenkins Projects are Jobs. Jobs can contain pipelines but they can also contain other workflows.

[Jenkins docs intro to pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)

> Jenkins **Pipeline** is a suite of plugins which supports implementing and integrating continuous delivery pipelines into Jenkins. Pipeline provides an extensible set of tools for modeling simple-to-complex delivery pipelines "as code" via the Pipeline DSL. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXon7.jpg)

[Jenkins Terminology](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology)

> **Job/Project:** Jenkins seems to use these terms interchangeably. They all refer to runnable tasks that are controlled / monitored by Jenkins.

Pipelines have a DSL (domain specific language) that only works within a Jenkins pipeline job. Here is an example of how to run an existing Job / Project on a Linux node within a pipeline project.

```
// specify your linux node by name
node('linux') {

    // run the project job named your-other-job
    stage('run project') {
        build 'your-other-job'
    }    

}
```

To dig deeper make sure to check out the helpful syntax generator built into Jenkins.
[image]

And [these pipeline examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this helpfull link :

[from-freestyle-to-pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/06/29/from-freestyle-to-pipeline/)